# MeekroDB - how to safely pass ORDER BY field names and arguments?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, meekro

I am using MeekroDB in a PHP project.  For some queries, I need to pass arbitrary field names to sort by.  There are NO examples of ORDER BY clauses on the meekro site.

How can I safely pass field names and avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities?  I realize I could check every field name with a list of valid fields beforehand, but I'm trying to make this code more generalized as a basic "get" function: function get(Array $filters, Array $sort_by)

Will the %b placeholder (backticks) be sufficient to protect against arbitrary code injection when passing field names?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY %b
```

Or for multiple fields:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY %lb
```

Is this safe?

Also, how can I then include the DESC or ASC modifiers arbitrarily as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use `b` and `lb` for the purpose, as both implemented using  [formatTableName](https://github.com/SergeyTsalkov/meekrodb/blob/master/db.class.php#L296) method that is safe.

Unfortunately, direction modifiers should be sanitized by hand, like this

```
$dirs  = ["ASC","DESC"]; 
$key   = array_search($_GET['dir'], $dirs); // see if we have such a value
$dir   = $dirs[$key]; //if not, first one will be set automatically. smart enuf :)
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY %b $dir"; //value is safe
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  How would I add multiple ORDER BY fields, each with its own direction modifier?  For example SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY `field1` DESC, `field2` ASC?  How would the actual meekro DB::query() function look?  (I realize I can iterate through the order fields and add a %b %l for each 'field' and 'direction' specifier. But I can't understand how to dynamically pass these to the DB::query function.

Comment: That will be a hard task. What I would suggest is to open an issue on the Meekro github, describing a situation and suggesting that both b and lb modifiers can accept an array consists of a field name and direction. Or you can go with your own suggestion with separate `b`s. I shouldn't be very complex.

Comment: Using separate %b and %l would require that an arbitrary number of parameters be passed to the DB::query () .  I would have to call it using eval which I don't feel is a good practice.  Any suggestions?

Comment: No need for eval ever. Since PHP 5.6 there is a great *splat* operator, when you can send an array for a function that accepts a list of parameters, just like that: `$results = DB::query($sql, ...$parameters);` If your PHP is outdated, then you have to stick with `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about that operator!  Perfect.